# Selected data pass to another controller is success, but display null in second view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, xml, asp.net-mvc

There are two views and two controller. In the first view it has list(created using select and options).when user select an item from the list and click the button, selected item should pass to the second view's controller.(used ajax).this process also success.after according to the selected item then in the other view I show details.

these are my codes.

**first controller and first view**

```
 public ActionResult First()
        {
            //get the location data
            var Loc = getData("Location", "", "", "");
            List<Firstdata> llc = new List<Firstdata>();
            foreach (var val in Loc)
            {
                llc.Add(new Firstdata
                {
                    Destination = val
                });
            }
            ViewBag.Loc = llc;
            return View();
        }
```

[in here get data from the xml and display as lists.Status : succuss]

**this is the first view**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div>

                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label for="desti">Destination</label>
                    <select id="desti">

                        @foreach (var item1 in @ViewBag.Loc)
                        {
                            <option>@item1.Destination</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div id="chk">
                   @Html.ActionLink("GO", "Check", new { style="dispaly:block;color:green;"})
                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**this is how i pass selected item from first view to second controller**

```
$("#chk a").click(function () {
    var locationID = $("#desti").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Check","Cruise")',
        data: { 'LocationID': locationID },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });

});
```

Status :success

**this is my second controller**

```
 public ActionResult Check(string LocationID)
{

    var Nam = getData("Location", "Name", LocationID, "");
    List<Firstdata> nf = new List<Firstdata>();
    foreach (var val in Nam)
    {
        nf.Add(new Firstdata
        {
            Nameof = val
        });
    }


    ViewBag.f = nf;

    return View();
  }
```

Status :success[selected item assigned to **LocationID**], go through the loop. nf count also **not null** and return to it's viwe.

**this is the second view**

```
<body>
    <div id="divf" style="width:300px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;">
        <h2>bbb</h2>
     @foreach(var itm in @ViewBag.f)
     {
         <h2>@itm.Nameof</h2>
     }

    </div>
```

-- In here go through the loop[When I put a breakpoint it shows itm count and assigned to header tag.] .but after go through the loop, it display nothing.
I have tried lot and I'm new to mvc.
**I am using xml data here[get data from xml file inside my project]**

Comment: As a side note, and thus not an answer to your question, you shouldn't return your data to the view using `ViewBag`. You should return it via the view (e.g. `return View(llc);`). You then have a type safe model in your view which will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: Your have asked numerous versions of this question have have had multiple comments and an the answer - i.e. to render the view your second method returns in the success callback `success: function (data) { $(someElement).html(data); }` What part of this can you not understand

Comment: what do you mean by someElement.tell me using my second view. I tried with this, but it didn't work, thats why I'm asking again and again.

Comment: Add a `<div id="placeholder"></div>` in your **first view**. Then its `success: function (data) { $('#placeholder').html(data); }`

Comment: This is not working @Stephen Muecke. What I want is not to display the data that I passed,In here  I pass selected item value to my second controller and using that do some sorting in my second controller. after that I display sorted data in second view. anyway thanx for your try

Comment: Then why on earth are you using ajax Suggest you do some research to understand what ajax is. If you want to redirect, then redirect!

Comment: I used ajax to pass the value of selected item from the list second controller. I'm not sure the  way I used it is correct. thats why I'm asking